# Moving SQLite database from android phone to emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, import, android-emulator, move

I have my app with some data. I'd like to test my sqlite database (from my phone) in Android emulator. I'm 99% sure It was working some time ago using the same method.

I know where are my database files, I know how to use PUSH and PULL DDMS features.

Maybe something change in new SDK?

This is how I'm moving my SQLite database from phone to androim emulator.

1. I've got rooted phone and created android emulator in eclipse. My database file is in /data/data//databases/file.db

I can copy this file from my phone to my desktop.

1. I've got sqlite database file, I can open it in (for example) SQLite Manager. I see my database structure with data. Everything is OK.
2. Now, I'm moving my database file to android emulator. I've got my app already installed.
   I'm using "Push a file onto the device" from DDMS. OK. It works. My file was uploaded to emulator.

But. When I'd like to see my database schema using emulator, this is what I get:
**Error: database disk image is malformed**

(this is error from adb console).

My app can't see this database.

Doing the same thing on my phones - no problems.
Is there a bug in android emulator or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using rooted phone with 2.3.4 (CM7.1-RC1).
My emulator is using API level 10 (2.3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Ok this isn't an answer to solve your problem directly, but instead of copying your database from your phone to the emulator, wasting countless hours of hair pulling, why don't you create some test scripts to fill your database upon installing the app? That way you just push the new version to your phone, run it, and you are set.

Comment: Yes. You're right but :) ... for me it was the fastest way to import my real phone data. I'm just sending .db file via dropbox and that's it. I need to think about other way of doing this but sometimes I've got some tests .db's from my friends. I need to think about another export feature. 

I'm just curious if this is some kind of emulator problem/bug. You know, just like the old one with GPS.